# How to pass a pandas series, a list and two constant strings as arguments for multiprocessing using multiprocessing.pool?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, windows, multiprocessing

I am trying to parallel process a function `func1` which take multiple parameters of different type and varying length. I am executing this in another function `other_func`.

The `pandas_series_var` is a `pandas.Series` object of different length compared to `list_3_elements` variable which is a `list`.

Whereas `color` is a `str` and `color_value` is `int`.

I tried making `pandas_series_var` a `global`, but it's not identified in the `func1` and causes a `pandas_series_var not defined` error.

```
def func1 (list_3_elements, color, color_value):
    # pandas_series_var is not defined error during parallel process
    # function does something

def other_func(*args):
    # All variable initialised
    global pandas_series_var
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        result = pool.starmap(func1, zip(list_3_elements, repeat(color),
                              repeat(color_value) ))
```

How can I pass all the variables to the func1 and use the multiprocessing power or any easy method to make the pandas series available globally?

I am using Windows and Python 3.8.

### Edit

I tried one more approach the code is working but it is now taking even more time.

```
p = [ {"series_obj":pandas_series_var,"list_elements":list_3_elements[0] ,"color":color,"color_value":color_value},

{"series_obj":pandas_series_var,"list_elements":list_3_elements[1] ,"color":color,"color_value":color_value},
{"series_obj":pandas_series_var,"list_elements":list_3_elements[2] ,"color":color,"color_value":color_value}
]



 def func1 (p):
        pandas_series_var = p["series_obj"]
        list_3_elements = p["list_elements"]
        color = p["color"]
        color_value = p["color_value"]
        # function does something



    def other_func(*args):
        # All variable initialised
        global pandas_series_var
        with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
            result = pool.map(func1,p)
```

This approach is taking more time but I am able to pass arguments to the code. What I want to do is the list_elements have a 3 models which I want to apply to the pandas series object. I am very new to multiprocessing. how can this be rewritten.

Comment: Processes run in separate memory-spaces so you cannot share `global` variables between them. Instead you must pass the  data between them as arguments (which must be picklable), use a `multiprocessing.Queue`, or use a `multiprocessing.Manger` to exchange the data.

Comment: If  `list_3_elements` is a list of 3 elements, then `func1` will be invoked 3 times each time with one of the elements of that list. So why are you calling the first argument  to `func1` `list_3_elements`? I just want to make sure you know what you are doing. Also, you can do `result = pool.map(functools.partial(func1, color=color, color_value=value), list_3_elements)`. No need to repeat constant values and use `zip` and `starmap`.

Comment: @martineau I tried reading through documentation and looked over some other stack overflow answers. It did not work. Can you post a sudo code here. using `multiprocessing,Manger` .

Comment: `multiprocessing.Manager`s are documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers).

Comment: Your code is missing the required (on Windows) `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement in the main module. See the **Safe importing of main module** section of multiprocessing's [Programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines). I suggest you find and read some `multiprocessing` tutorials before continuing because you obviously aren't familiar with the fundamentals.

Comment: @martineau Yes I am new to `multiprocessing` . I tried another approach. But it is taking more time. could you help me with that.

Comment: If you need to pass a lot of data between the processes, the overhead involved in doing that can negate any gains that might be had from doing the processing concurrently. You might be able to avoid the need to do that by using the [`multiprocessing.shared_memory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html#module-multiprocessing.shared_memory) class that was added in Python 3.8 and *does* allow some types of data to be shared.